# Fresh Debian install / setup users per Babushka

Tags: linux, debian, configuration

I posted this question on the [babushka google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/babushka_app/FLKh4XB9QeY) , but I got since 5 days no response. I will try my luck here:

What is the correct way to setup some users with Babushka on a shiny 
new Debian box ?

I want simply know what is a good practice with this tool.

Let's say I want have a user "foobar", with rvm installed.

I have only the root user on my host, and Babushka is installed.

Should I first create the foobar user manualy and run with him via 
Babushka my rvm recipe ?

Or should I run babushka as root and let this tool create the user and 
instal rvm for them ? (I don't want a global rvm install, only for the 
foobar user)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the OP got the answer he wanted on the google group eventually - copy pasted here for future reference (and karma whoring)

> Hi Wojciech, sorry about the delay. Been a busy week. :)
>
> I sign in as root first in that case, and use babushka to create the
>   user.

```
babushka benhoskings:'user setup for provisioning' username=ben
```

> Then I sign in as that user and configure the account

```
babushka benhoskings:'user setup'
```

> Then I'd install rvm as normal. (I'm not an rvm user though.)
>
> When provisioning servers, I wrap this up in a dep that itself runs
>   multiple remote babushkas. I'll write it up soon, but you could speed
>   it up in the meantime with:

```
ssh root@host "babushka benhoskings:'user setup for provisioning' username=ben key='$(cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub)'" 
ssh ben@host "benhoskings:'user setup'" 
ssh ben@host "some-other-source:'rvm installed'"
```

> - Ben